# Group sheets with names in a string variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to group a number of sheets that has sheet names with in a string variable, the group of sheets will be used to format each sheet within the group.

The string (let's call it, SheetsFormat) contains all sheet names that need to be formatted, each value within the string was added into the dynamic string when it was created.

The question is how to create a group of sheets that reference the SheetsFormat string?

Example of the string contents: "Mon Maint", "Mon Mgnt", "Tue Prod" etc.

The code I used was:

```
Dim ws as worksheet, ws_group As Worksheets
Set ws_group = Sheets(Array(SheetsFormat))
For Each ws In ws_group
'some staff
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample procedure to get you going. You can build your array in any number of ways, but the end result will follow this patter--iterating through an array (or similar) to do the same operations on the set of worksheets.

```
Sub SampleDoSomethingToMultipleSheets()

    Dim SheetsFormat(3) As String
    SheetsFormat(0) = "Mon Maint"
    SheetsFormat(1) = "Mon Mgnt"
    SheetsFormat(2) = "Tue Prod"

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = 0 To UBound(SheetsFormat) - 1
        With Sheets(SheetsFormat(idx))
            ' put your code here, e.g.
            .Range("A1").Value = "StackOverflow is awesome"
        End With
    Next idx

End Sub
```

Comment: This will be much easier to maintain if you `Dim SheetFormat as Variant` and use `SheetFormats = Array ("Mon Maint", ...)` instead of calling them out by index.  Although maybe OP has some other way to make the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that does what you want. It uses the `Split` function which splits a string into an array based on a separator.

```
Sub LoopThroughSheetsString()
Dim SheetsFormat As String
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
SheetsFormat = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"

'loop through the array created by splitting SheetsFormat on commas
For Each ws In Sheets(Split(SheetsFormat, ","))
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

Note that it's one long string with double-quotes only at the beginning and end.

Comment: Using `/` as the delimiter would ensure that it cannot conflict with a sheet name.